# Composer: how to know a package by what other package is required

Tags: composer-php

I've found `nesbo/carbon` in my `vendor` folder. It is a really useful library and I'm curious to know which other package I installed requires it.

How can I know this?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Lets look at `composer why` or `composer depends` command. This command shows which other packages depend on a certain package. [Show usage](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#depends)

This is usage example

```
 $ composer depends psr/log
 symfony/debug  v3.2.2  requires  psr/log (~1.0)
```

Comment: No, I don't want to know the requirements of `nesbot/carbon` but which other packages require it.

Comment: @Aerendir That's exactly what `composer depends` does - give it a try and see!